# Geocoding large amount of postcodes crashing in MMQGIS

Tags: qgis, geocoding, mmqgis

I have 14,000 observations I am geocoding to postcodes around London and surrounding areas.

I have 2 files - London postcodes and Britain postcodes. Around 2,000 postcodes fall outside of London so I have to use the postcodes for the UK, which is considerably larger.

QGIS is crashing each time I am geocoding to the UK postcode file, presumably as it has to index 1.8 million postcodes before matching the remaining 2,000. What alternative do I have?

For reference, geocoding 12,000 postcodes in London took a matter of minutes.

Comment: If each observation has a postcode, and you have the associated postcode with geography in the UK postcodes, isn't this just a join? And to make it even easier, a a database such as SQLite should have no problem with this.

Comment: There are many observations per postcode rather than just one. I'll have a look at sqlite as it's something i've not used before

Comment: Exactly ... this will allow you to assign geometry to every observation...